# Javascript Chart Draw

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am using Google Charts API to integrate into a group project. The project is a visualisation toolkit for social media trends and such.

The problem is though, I have written a PHP program that visualises pie/bar/line charts etc. But I am only able to get them to work by declaring:

```
var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
```

to visualise the individual charts. However I wish to create individual files for the visualisations. i.e. drawPie, drawLine, drawBar etc. This is so it would be able to work with a rule based data type tool we have created i.e. percentage and location could be drawn onto a pie chart.

Anyway I am having trouble with each individual file. Below is the code for the drawPie.js file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Load JSAPI -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src='https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={"modules":[{"name":"visualization","version":"1","packages":["corechart","table"]}]}'></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<!-- Load the API Package -->
    google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['controls']});
    //<!-- Callback when the Google Visualization API is Loaded -->
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);

    function drawPie() {

    //<!-- Create the Table -->
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'location');
    data.addColumn('number', 'crimes');
    data.addRows([ <?php echo $data_for_chart; ?> ]);
    //<!-- Pass Options -->
    var options = {
    'legend': 'left',
    'title': 'Crimes (per day)',
    'is3D': 'True',
    'width':700,
    'height':300
    };

    //<!-- Instantiate and Draw Chart -->
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('pie_chart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
    </script>
</head>
    <body>
        <style> pie_chart {margin: 0 auto; }</style>
        <div id="pie_chart"></div>

        <style>
            #left { margin-left: 15%; float: left; }
            #right { margin-right: 15%; float: right; }
            img { width: 200; height: 200;}
        </style>
    </body>
```

The code doesn't show the chart. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am also using the "$data_for_chart;" which uses the PHP to connect to the database to retrieve the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading the wrong package.

Change `google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['controls']});` to `google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});` and it should work. If it doesn't, you have another problem beyond this (relatively simple) one.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, but yes, this worked for me. Thank you.